# How do we set scalac options for test environment, not just test file tree?

Tags: scala, scalac

We want to cause scalac warnings to fail our build in the test/CI environment, but not in a dev environment.  We tried this in our build.sbt:

```
scalacOptions in Test += "-Xfatal-warnings"
```

However, what that does is cause warnings in the test *tree* to fail the build (even in the dev environment), but warnings elsewhere do not.

What is the proper way to enable fatal-warnings for all code in the test environment, but not elsewhere?

Comment: What do you use for CI? Jenkins?

Comment: I guess you could pick up extra optional scalacOptions from an environment variable (that you could set on CI).